# iOS mobile browsers ignores transition-duration CSS property

Tags: ios, css, mobile-browser

I'm working on service, which allows you to paste at your site a button for some actions. It sticked to bottom of screen normally, but for some reasons it floating when user scale page or scroll when scaled. Code works perfectly on Android and Win, but not working on iOS, on any browser. Coordinates of div changing by script at events, div has style

```
 transition-duration: 1000ms;
```

which makes him slowly float to new position on scroll instead of instant move. Tested on iPhones 5, 6, 7. Can somebody explain why that happens?

Comment: Try adding -webki-transition-duration: 1000ms; It would be wiser to use a autoprefixer for prefixing CSS for cross browser support.

Comment: Nope. I have tried all of prefixes.